# Find the volume of the part of the vessel under water

Tags: volume

I am struggling to find the volume of the part of the vessel that is partially under water in the third figure (the one where the elephant is on top). Is there anything missing from the given parameters? If not, how can I find the volume of that part? I can compute the volume of a triangular prism, but, as you can see, there is a small portion where I can't think of a way to find the height of it.[image: figure]

Comment: Which portion can't you find the height of?

Comment: I need the height of the triangle (third figure). Then, the volume of the part under water would be equal to the volume of the triangular prism plus the volume of the rectangle.

Comment: A 30-degree right triangle, the length of the other leg is known ... Somehow you got the base of the smaller prism in the "before" figure, which is a similar problem to solve.

Comment: Could you please be more clear?

Comment: The dotted line divides the bottom triangle into two 30-degree right triangles. It also divides the 5-meter base of the triangle in half.